# Is there a function whose definite integrals are all 0?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there a continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \in [0,1]$ and, if we define
$F_n(x) = \int_{0} ^ {x} F_{n-1}(t) dt $ (where $F_0(x)=f(x)$),
then $\int_0^1 F_n(x)dx = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What kind of integration do you mean? That will affect my answer.

Comment: @amcalde I don't see how, when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: OK, I missed the continuous part. I believe you now.

Comment: What can I definitely say is that $[0;1]$ is not principal, we can change it to any convenient for us segment, for instance, $[-1,1]$.